# MomentJs convert milliseconds to days

Tags: momentjs

I am new to moment.js. I want to convert milliseconds to days. When I tried in normal converter in google it is showing `377.7613437963 days`, but programatically it is showing `11 days`.

```
var duration = moment.duration(32638528433, 'milliseconds');
var days = duration.days();
console.log(days);
```

Comment: full year + 11 days = 377 days isn't it?

Comment: yes. It is ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `asDays()` if you want `377.7613437963` as output.

As the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/) says:

> As with the other getters for durations, `moment.duration().days()` gets the days (0 - 30).
>
> `moment.duration().asDays()` gets the length of the duration in days.

Here a live example:

```js
var duration = moment.duration(32638528433, 'milliseconds');
var days = duration.asDays();
console.log(days);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```